# PHP Exception Handling breaking user creation script

Tags: php, exception, pdo, try-catch

I've been stuck on this one issue for about three days now and I'm starting to get frustrated. When I run the code below without the try catch blocks it works fine. However, once I wrap it in try catch blocks it doesn't work. I've checked the php manual and searched forums and even my old code but for whatever reason it just won't work. I've even tried changing servers, I've gone through XAMPP, MAMP, and a Turnkey LAMP server. Non of which fixed the problem.

```
 <?php

//Pull variables from post array
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_pw = $_POST['confirm_password'];
$acc_type   = $_POST['account_type'];

try{
    require_once('../connection/create_conn.php');

    //build bound sql statment
    $create_user = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email, password, account_type)
                 VALUES(:first, :last, :user, :email, :pass, :acc)";

            //prepare the statment
            $cmd = $db->prepare($create_user);

            //bind the parameters to the sql placeholders
            $cmd->bindParam(':first', $first_name , PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
            $cmd->bindParam(':last' , $last_name  , PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
            $cmd->bindParam(':user' , $username   , PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
            $cmd->bindParam(':email', $email      , PDO::PARAM_STR, 254);
            $cmd->bindParam(':pass' , $password   , PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
            $cmd->bindParam(':acc'  , $acc_type   , PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

            $cmd->execute();

            $db = null;

}catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'error';
}

?>
```

I'm a bit out of practice so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try once echo $e->getMessage(); it will state you what problem is occur?

Comment: I have tried that, the thing that confuses me is that no error occurs, what happens is it just doesn't upload the user information to the database, even when I try to catch the PDO exception no error message is given.

Comment: Ok, try to do if($cmd->execute()){ $db = null;}else{ through new Exception('some message')}; and then catch as i suggested.

Comment: Hey so I followed your instructions and it did throw an error this time. I'm not sure what I'm looking for here though.

Comment: actually its strange because your code is correct. so it's tough to figure out for us. if you are able to show this on fiddle or somewhere else may be we can. And please put require_once outside out of try and past it just after <?php